# Missing something from Security 101 - No Sudo -> Boot to Recovery -> Add to admin -> Voila?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, root

May be this is a silly question but yesterday I found myself struggling to execute the `sudo` command because apparently I was taken off the list on my own machine for some reason. What I did was to restart my operating system (Ubuntu) and boot into the recovery console and execute:

```
adduser <username> admin
```

and it said, `user <username> was successfully added into the admin group`. I start my operating system and voila, I have `sudo` privileges as expected. I am totally confused and must have been sleeping in class but is this good or bad? Of course, I am totally happy that I got back my privileges but...

Can I just restart **any** machine and add myself to the admin group or was I able to do this because this was ***my*** machine? Any thoughts?

Comment: First lesson from Security 101: Once an attacker has physical access, all bets are off. Everything else just builds on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhat harmless, because if you have physical access to the machine so you can boot into the recovery console, you can do anything you want anyway. You could just pull the plug and steal the harddrive, and mount it in another computer, do anything you want with any of the files.

Even if you only have "non-physical, virtually physical" access such as via KVM-over-IP or what they're called, you could *still* boot any other system and mount the disk, and send any data over the network, or do whatever you want.

Which leads to the solution: If you want to prevent someone from doing such a thing, use an encrypted file system such as Truecrypt or similar (or, at least, use an encrypted home folder, which Ubuntu supports out of the box, and which should be enough).

Comment: Nothing will __ever__ _prevent_ someone from doing something nasty. Security will at most ever will make attacks __easier to detect and significantly slower (and arguably harder)__ +1 nevertheless.

Comment: True. Though of course an encrypted filesystem (assuming a not-trivially-guessable, non-dictionary password, and a non-broken crypto implementation) is admittedly beyond the scope of most attackers. Maybe the NSA will have no trouble breaking the encryption (though they will probably instead just hood and waterboard you until you tell the password -- that's cheaper), but any random person who walks past your computer (or steals it) won't get very far. Which likely is just good enough for anyone not selling nuclear weapon secrets.